# what's wrong with this error?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I use zend partial helper:

```
   <?php echo $this->partial(include_once('../application/views/layouts/header.phtml'), array('from' => '<div id="logo_page"><img src="../css/images/master1.png"></div>')); ?>
```

In header.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->escape($this->from) ?>
```

when i try to use it, i have error:

> exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'script '**1**' not found in
>   path
>   (Y:/home/local.mekheda/application/modules/blog/views\scripts/;Y:\home\local.mekheda\application/views\scripts/)'
>   in Y:\home\local.mekheda\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php:980

Why it's 1 and what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `include_once` directive. Use only the path to the partial view:

```
$this->partial('../application/views/layouts/header.phtml', array('from' => '<div id="logo_page"><img src="../css/images/master1.png"></div>'));
```

The `include_once` returns `1` on success, hence the error message.

**Update:**
Not sure I completely understand the question from your comment, but why not put all the HTML in the partial view:

```
// header.phtml
<div id="logo_page"><img src="<?php echo $this->img; ?>" /></div>
```

And pass it to the partial view as follows:

```
$this->partial('../application/views/layouts/header.phtml', array('img' => 'css/images/master.pg'));
```

**Note:** if the file `css/images/master.png` is under your `public` directory you can pass it as I did, without using `../`

Comment: Requested scripts may not include parent directory traversal ("../", "..\" notation)
i tried diffrent pathes i have this error

Comment: Yes, correct. You should place the partial views in the same folder, where your view is. [RTFM](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) to see how it's done. ;-)

Comment: what if i need it in diffrent views? do i need to duplicate header.html?

Comment: Once again, [RTFM](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial), see Example #10 for an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You use partial wrong - throw the `include_once` statement

```
echo $this->partial(
    '../application/views/layouts/header.phtml',
    array('from' => '<div id="logo_page"><img src="../css/images/master1.png"></div>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Place “header.phtml” in YourApplicationFolder/modules/Application/view/partials

```
< ?php echo $this->partial('partials/header.phtml',
                            array('from' => '<div id="logo_page"><img src="../css/images/master1.png"></div>')); ?>
```

Comment: with message 'script '/partials/header.phtml' not found in path

Comment: Place “header.phtml” in YourApplicationFolder/modules/Application/view/partials

Comment: maybe you know in my array this string: '<div id="logo_page"><img src="../css/images/master1.png"></div>' and html response it like text, but not html tugs, what can i do?